# UIImageView size relative to screen size

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I have an UIImageView, with an image like so

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "imageName")
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

On the iPhone X this image looks great with 140x140 dimensions
Maybe needless to say, this does not look great on the iPhone5s, since 140x140 would take up too much of screen space

How can I correctly scale my image for other screen dimensions, what would be the best practice for this?

As for now, I set the image height and width to

```
let size = UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 5.5
imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size),
imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size),
```

Since that will be pretty close to what I am after. But I can't shake the feeling that there are better alternatives than this

Comment: Why setting the imageView size explicitly, when you can use constraints? For ex: you can position the imageView in Storyboard the way you like, then right-click and drag from the imageView to the contentView (UIView), and select ```Aspect Ratio```. This way, it will maintain the same aspect ratio on every screen size.

Comment: You can set a base size in points, say 45pt, and multiply that with `UIScreen.main.scale`. You would get 135px on iPhone X and 90px on iPhone 5.

Comment: @Starsky I am doing all programatically. The image will also be inside a stackView, that will increase in height, depending on how many elements that are in it. So the image won't be fixed to a position, if that makes sense

@Desdenova I will try this one, but how exactly does points work? Just; `let viewSize = 45 * UIScreen.main.scale` ?

Comment: @klskl Yes, just like that. and you may want to read this to get what's going on. https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions

Comment: @Desdenova thanks! If I understand this correctly, then perhaps I can supply the assets in the correct x1,x2,x3 dimensions, and then just scale them directly with `UIScreen.main.scale`, and skip the whole static "45", it seems to work atleast!

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit broad like "What do you think guys?", but still.

---

It's better to change your size accordingly to your parent view, not screen.

```swift
imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.2, constant: 0)
imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
```